# In Apache Ranger, how to create service in hdfs-plugin with Rest Api call?

Tags: apache-ranger

I am trying to create a service in hdfs-plugin. I am refering this link.

I have tried below curl command:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"configs": {"password": "*****","username": "admin"},"description":"hdfsservice","isEnabled": true,"name": "hadoopdev","type": "test","version": 1}' http://localhost:6080/service/public/v2/api/service
When I ran this it didn't give any response, not even any error.

Can someone help me to know if this is the correct curl or not?